# How to add element in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi all I have following code:

```
      const category = useSelector(state => state.category.category);

      const list = [];

      const addlist = (id, name) => {
        const data = {
          id: name,
        };
        list.push(data);
    
 };
```

I am getting from my state `category`. Then I am creating empty `list` array and finally I have `addlist` function  who is added item in my `list` array.

here is my select options:

```
    return(
     <div>
       <select name="cars" id="cars">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                choose category
          </option>
           {category?.map((item, idx) => (
              <option
                  key={item.id}
                  value={idx}
                  disabled={active}
                  onClick={() => addlist(item.id, item.name)}
                >
                  {item.name}
               </option>
              ))}
         </select>
     </div>
    )
```

I am trying to implement following, when some option will be clicked it should be automatically added in array. But after clicking nothing was happening. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your list array needs to be in state for react to be aware of any changes

Comment: Suggested documentation to read is [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment section, for similar scenarios where you'd like to keep values for example in an array in your component you should use `useState` hook.

You can import `useState` as:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
```

A basic idea would be the following - see how the `onClick` has changed:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const category = useSelector(state => state.category.category);
  // here you can create a list state with an initial empty array
  const [list, setList] = useState([])
  
  return(
    <div>
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
         <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
               choose category
         </option>
          {category?.map((item, idx) => (
             <option
                 key={item.id}
                 value={idx}
                 disabled={false} // originally here was active
                 onClick={() => setList(prevState => [...prevState, {
                   id: item.name
                 }])}
               >
                 {item.name}
              </option>
             ))}
        </select>
    </div>
   )
}
```

But the essential part other than creating a `list` state would be:

```
setList(prevState =>
   [...prevState, { id: item.name }]
)
```

Suggested documentation to read is [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).